# LTspice parameters

Tags: power-electronics, ltspice, common-mode-choke, ti-ccstudio

I want to know how the .mod/.lib files in Ltspice are created by manufacturers. Let's say we have a Common Mode Choke (CMC). It will have some parameters as per its equivalent model at different freq range. How are those parameters modelled?

In SP4 file we know, it is taken from VNA measurement. (CMC in this case) Is it the same for Spice?

Answer (score 0):

Spice has a number of built in primitives, resistors, capacitors,inductors, diodes, transistors, sources, etc.

These primitives have parameters, for example a transistor will have parameters like forward beta, inter-electrode capacitances, early voltage and so on, these can all be set in a .MODEL statement. Basically Spice knows how to model a transistor, so manufacturers just need to release a model with all the parameters set to match their product.

For components that don’t have a direct primitive a sub-circuit can be used to build the device from multiple primitives, so you might have a choke model that contains inductors, resistors and capacitors.

How the model works at different frequencies wouldn’t be explicitly stated in the model, rather it would be  consequence of the primitives used and their parameters.